# MongoDB - unauthorized

Tags: mongodb

I need your help regarding MongoDb server.

I've made an app with PHP and MongoDB that works very well on my localhost but I'm having troubles once I try to put into production.

All the drivers are installed to make it work but I just can't query anything...

```
 > show dbs
 Wed Sep 13 11:18:32.964 listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:46
 >
```

I can't create an user either....

My environment : Linux Debian 8, MongoDB version 2.4.10

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the authentification is correct?. You can check by:

```
> db.auth("user", "passwrd")
```

on your localhost your app may work because mongo does't require authentification by default.